# Display Sum of Specific Rows for All rows in a Column - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, row

I have the following table below and I want to calculate sum of Amount where Location =  USA grouped by Date and display it in a new column for all rows (even not USA). I can't drop any of the columns for the result.

[image]

I am able to pull Sum of Amount per Date, but not per USA per Date:

```
SELECT Date, Name, Location, Amount, sum(Amount) over (PARTITION BY Date) AS "USA Amount Sum" 
FROM Table
```

Which gives me:

[image]

But I want:

[image]

*Using PostgreSQL*

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Date, Name, Location, Amount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'USA' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Date) AS "USA Amount Sum" 
FROM tablename;
```

or:

```
SELECT Date, Name, Location, Amount, 
       COALESCE(SUM(Amount) FILTER (WHERE Location = 'USA') OVER (PARTITION BY Date), 0) AS "USA Amount Sum" 
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6e8a225fb76a6e4c64399f615d0f71a1).